# How to display only one button on UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have implemented UILocalNotification. Everything is working fine and i can see the Notification also. I can see the notification and it shows me two button "cancel" and "View" from which i do not want "view" button can i do this?

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi sorry for late reply you can Have only Ok button for UilocalNotifications
by doing this

notif.hasAction=NO;

by doing this you cannot see view button in the notifications Hope it solved your Problem

Answer (score 0):

No. you can not do this. because local notification generated from ios u only change the name of view button by alertAction property.

Answer (score 0):

i think its not possible to show one button in nslocal notification

```
 notification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"hello", nil); // its set instead of view to hello.
 notification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(nil, nil); // default view Name is coming For action Button to application
```

Comment: ya ...i already did but some doubt if i set to nil then its taking view by deafault